# how to do jquery form submit using Ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

In my java application I'm submitting the form using JQuery.

Here is the code in my jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<fieldset id="profile_proffiesional">
    <form:form action="profile/awards" modelAttribute="AWARDS">
        <p>
            <label for="position">Position</label>
            <form:input path="position" tabindex="4" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="location">Location</label>
            <form:input path="location" tabindex="5" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <form:input path="description" tabindex="5" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </p>
    </form:form>
</fieldset>
<script>
    $('#AWARDS').ajaxForm({
        target : '#body',
        success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            alert(responseText);
        },
        beforeSubmit : function() {
            $.blockUI({
                message : '<h1> Just a moment...</h1>'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Problem is when I click Submit button, where the form goes and it shows the response with alert. When I click `OK` button in alert window, the same success message will get printed on window, in the place of form.

And the Form gets totally invisible, when I refresh it and the success message will be removed and the form is shown.

But I want to display success on alert and not on the screen.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `target : '#body'` will do the trick.

That particular line update the content of the body with the response.